# Finding the area of the surface of the cylinder $y^2+z^2=9$ that lies above rectangle with vertices $(0, 0)$,$ (4, 0)$,$ (0, 2), (4, 2).$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I found $f_x=0$, $f_y = -\frac{y}{\sqrt{9-y^2}}$

$\int^4_0\int^2_0\sqrt{(-\frac{y}{\sqrt{9-y^2}})^2}dydx$

and tried to use substitution with $u=9-y^2$, getting

$-\frac{1}{2}\int^2_0u^{-0.5}du$ for the inner integral.

$(\frac{1}{4})(9-y^2)^{0.5}|^2_0$

$\frac{1}{4}[(9-2^2)-(9-0)]=\frac{5-9}{4}$

... but all of this is far off from the book answer of $12\sin^{-1}(2/3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Your integral should be
$$\int^4_{x=0}\int^2_{y=0}\sqrt{1+\left(-\frac{y}{\sqrt{9-y^2}}\right)^2}dydx=\int^4_{x=0}\int^2_{y=0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(y/3)^2}}dydx.$$